# Snapshot views of services disabled when Razor plugin is added to ServiceStack.Net in v3.9.45

Tags: servicestack

The snapshot of service data is good to use in development as I first write the service and see if it's returning data and then write the view. However after I upgraded to ServiceStack v3.9.45 it looks like the Razor2 plugin prevents snapshot information being generated. Probably the request never gets that far if there is no view for it.

Is it possible to have the best of both worlds and return snapshot data if there is no defined view? :)